# Hive partition column

Tags: hive, hiveql, partition, hive-partitions

We have avro partitioned table in hive. When we query table, partition column is displaying at the end. Is there any way to display partition column at first?

Eg: `select * from tablea`

Output:

```
Col1 col2 partition_column
```

Expected output:

Partition_column col1 col2

Answer (score 1):

Partition column is not stored in files, so, avro or not avro, it does not matter in this context. Partition column corresponds partition sub-folder within table folder and stored in the metadata.

Historically partition column is the last one.  dynamic partitioning using `Insert`overwrite table partition (partition_column) SELECT * from ...` is rather common scenario. Hive will know partition is the last column.

> The dynamic partition columns must be specified last among the columns
>   in the SELECT statement and in the same order in which they appear in
>   the PARTITION() clause.

You can change the order of columns displayed when running `SELECT *` only by creating a `view` in which you list all columns in the required order, OR select columns explicitly in your select.

Also according to the Codd's theory, column and row order is immaterial, you always must specify columns order desired explicitly in the select and rows order using ORDER BY, instead of relying on columns order and row order in the table or view. But in Hive the partitioning column is the last one in the table.

Consider also this: You may even not know, what you selecting from: table or view. And you may be not notified that upstream system decided to change the table or view eventually. View or table can change the order of columns. Consider view the same as a table when doing selects. It is just abstraction level.  Use explicit column list to make your program working reliably always and do not have strong dependency on column order in the underlying table/view, which is immaterial.